# Adding suffix to the barcode scanner

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, quaggajs

How can we add suffix to the barcode, so that after scanning it triggers the next function ?

In my case I would like to use Quagga js plugin and Angular 4 framework. Can someone shed some light to proceed with it?

Comment: You have the `Quagga.onDetected(callback)` callback, which provides the decoded string. You can then process it further. What should the suffix do?

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer hai..,i would like to trigger an angular function..,instead of using a button